# Imprimir archivo txt desde api publicada en IIS

Tags: cmd, iis, imprimir

Hola mi problema es el siguiente:
Estoy haciendo uso de una api para imprimir un archivo .txt que se encuntra guardado en una carpeta local "Muestro codigo que manda a imprimir"

```
Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C COPY /B C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\zqr\\BD\\QR_final.txt \\\\SERVER_1\\Impresora_1";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.Start();
            process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();
```

cuando ejecuto la api de manera local funciona todo perfectamente pero al publicarla en IIS no imprime el archivo.
Al principio creia que la manera de imprimir estaba mal hecha, asi que implementamos otra forma pero sigue sin imprimir. Con esto confirmamos que el IIS es problema, aunque no sabemos que configuracion se tiene que hacer para poder hacerlo funcionar.
O si existe otra forma de mandar a imprimir sin usar hacer uso del cmd.exe ya que el IIS no permite ejecutarlo por seguridad

Comment: Puede ser un asunto de permisos, verifica que el usuario de iis tenga permisos de ejecución para cmd.exe

Comment: Hola gracias por responder!! solo tengo el ususario administrador en el servicio de iis, por ende tiene todos los permisos, lo que me sorprende que realizo las prubas de manera local y funciona perfecto el problema surge del iis, he verificada que el archivo se este actulizando cada que mando imprimir y lo hace la fecha de modificacion se actualiza pero la orden que mande a imprimir nunca llega

Comment: Probaste con UseShellExecute =true ???

Comment: Si bro y sigue igual :( incluso verifique que los controladores de la impresora esten correctos, reglas de active directory y todo esta libre para una buen comunicacion

Comment: ¿Ya pudiste solucionar tu inconveniente? Tengo el mismo problema, necesito descargar un archivo desde mi servidor, cuando corro el módulo que desarrollé desde mi Local me funciona normalmente, me descarga el archivo que necesito sin problema. Pero cuando publico el modulo y lo subo a la IIS, funciona perfectamente todo el modulo, pero cuando le doy en la opción imprimir, no me descarga el archivo que necesito con el diseño para realizar la impresión.